# One line Hello World java project, Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking

Tags: java, eclipse

First got this error with Eclipse Neon. Installed Oxygen and get the same error. Under Oxygen, I created a new Java project with a one line Main function to write "Hello, World!":

```
/**
 */
package com.brindlewaye.hello;

/*
 * author Dave
 */
public class Hello {
    /*
     */
    public Hello() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /*
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Same error.

I have searched and found nothing that applied, IMHO, to a simple one line, Hello World, Java project.

What might the problem be?

Comment: So we're all on the same page here, how about you present the actual Java program, verbatim, as opposed to just describing it?

Comment: /**
 * 
 */
package com.brindlewaye.hello;

/**
 * author Dave
 *
 */
public class Hello
{

  /**
   * 
   */
  public Hello()
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
  }

}

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the problem is with your Eclipse installation, and possibly with other software installed on the machine, not with this particular program.  A now-deleted answer to this question suggested a poor interaction between Eclipse and security software running on the machine, though the specific issue mentioned there appeared to be different from yours.  There are, I'm afraid, many other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my Eclipse workspace had gone wonky. Created a new workspace and migrated all of my Java projects to it. Now all of them build and run fine.